# Eclipse c++ Neon não reconhece Toolchain

Tags: c++, eclipse

Estou tentando instalar o eclipse em um computador, e ele não reconhece a toolchain do GCC já mudei os Path e tudo mas não aparece na hora de criar um projeto, alguém já enfrentou esse problema ou sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era que a versão do GNU que eu estava tentando usar não era suportada pelo eclipse